# Strange issue with Tomcat and AGS 10 .NET

Tags: arcgis-server, tomcat

I have one of my applications being deploying through Tomcat of Java WebADF.  It's being done by someone else, on another site.

It, as it would, worls perfectly on my box, but on their application, it fails.  Initially, all that displays is a empty page, with a Javascript error highlighted:

```
Message: 'EsriPageElement' is undefined

    Line: 17
    Char: 2
    Code: 0
    URI: http://Myserver:8080/MyApp/js/MA_startup.js
```

However, on investigating the Tomcat logs, I find this:

`SEVERE: Unable to initialize resource 'ags1'. This resource will be removed
com.esri.adf.web.ags.ADFAGSException: Cannot create MapServer instance for server object 'MyService' [hosts=[MyServer]]
    at com.esri.adf.web.ags.data.AGSLocalConnection.activateResource(Unknown Source)`

...and I am a bit perplexed.  The user is logging on as himself.  The only thing I can think of, is that this is permissions related, in that when Tomcat is fired up, it hasn't been started by anyone with the permissions to 'see' AGS?

Any ideas peeps?  Permissions?  IT Mice under the hood?  Too much alcohol abuse in my youth?  Am I bad and this is Karma?  I genuinely don't have a clue.

Comment: has the password changed since the original install? [90 days] - http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36437

Comment: Yes @Mapperz, all the post install was done.  Very confused as to why this is happening.